# kill() system call with SIGTERM is not working

Tags: c++, c, process, kill-process

I have created a binary using c++ in ubuntu which will run as a daemon and read the data from database and store it into a xml file.

and for stopping the daemon i am using this function but it is not working.

```
void stopService()
{
    int mypid;

    if(((mypid = validate_pid()) > 0) || ((mypid = validate_non_pid()) > 0)) {


        if(0 == kill(mypid, SIGTERM) ) {

            sleep(1);
        }
        else {
            printf("Stopping %s  [FAILED]\n", Service);// this line is getting printed.
        }

    }
    else {
        printf("Stopping %s  [ Failed ] Not Running....\n", Service);
    }

}
```

i'm getting the ouput as stopping the service [failed].

```
'validate_pid()' It will written the pid from /proc/some id/cmdline.
```

and 
    'validate_non_pid()' It will written the pid using pgrep.

I am not writing the complete code since it will become lengthy,

Thanks in advance.

and one thing i'm calling this function by taking command line argument and using this in switch();
    'case 'e':
        stopService();'

so how can i kill this process by usin kill().

Comment: You can check the `errno` to see why it failed. Maybe it's a permission issue.

Comment: I have printed the pid and killed the process manually from terminal But using sudo, without sudo it has given me an error saying 'kill: (9315) - Operation not permitted'.

Comment: Try replacing kill() with 'int raise(int)' + 'void (*signal(int, void (*func)(int)))(int);'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be a permission issue.
 Print the Process Id using

```
'getpid();'
```

Kill it manually from terminal.

```
'sudo kill -9 processid'
```